# Setting name of Chrome Extension in self-hosting (update.xml)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-apps

I have an extension I am hosting on a server using the Autoupdating scheme described [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/autoupdate), and then installing this on a Google Apps domain through the Admin console.

When adding the extension as a custom app, it can only be identified by its id, which is kind of ugly and opaque:

[image]

Is there a field in the update.xml or something that I can use to set a friendly name, and/or an icon?